# csv delete rows using Java

Tags: java, csv

I already convert csv to a shapefile and show it on a map the question here is how can I manage the csv data and delete rows whish speed are less than 5 in the same converting code it is possible to do that?

here is part of my code hen i convert csv to shapefile

```
public class Csv2shape {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Set cross-platform look & feel for compatability
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());

    File file = JFileDataStoreChooser.showOpenFile("csv", null);
    if (file == null) {
        return;
    }
    /*
     * We use the DataUtilities class to create a FeatureType that will describe the data in our
     * shapefile.
     * 
     * See also the createFeatureType method below for another, more flexible approach.
     */
    final SimpleFeatureType TYPE = DataUtilities.createType(    "Location",
            "the_geom:Point:srid=4326," + // <- the geometry attribute: Point type
            "Date:String," +   // <- a String attribute
            "Heure:String," +   // <- a String attribute        
            "latitude:String," +   // <- a String attribute
            "vitesse:Double"   // a number attribute
    );
    System.out.println("TYPE:"+TYPE);

     /* A list to collect features as we create them.
     */
    List<SimpleFeature> features = new ArrayList<SimpleFeature>();

    /*
     * GeometryFactory will be used to create the geometry attribute of each feature,
     * using a Point object for the location.
     */
    GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();

    SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(TYPE);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    try {
        /* First line of the data file is the header */
        String line = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Header: " + line);

        for (line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {
            if (line.trim().length() > 0) { // skip blank lines
                String tokens[] = line.split("\\,");
                String name1 = tokens[0].trim();
                String name2 = tokens[1].trim();
                double latitude = Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);
                double longitude = Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]);
                String name = tokens[4].trim();
                String name4 = tokens[5].trim();

                /* Longitude (= x coord) first ! */
                Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude));

                featureBuilder.add(point);
                featureBuilder.add(name1);
                featureBuilder.add(name2);
                featureBuilder.add(name);
                featureBuilder.add(name4);
                SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);
                features.add(feature);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }

    /*
     * Get an output file name and create the new shapefile
     */
    /*
     * Get an output file name and create the new shapefile
     */
    File newFile = getNewShapeFile(file);

    ShapefileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory = new ShapefileDataStoreFactory();

    Map<String, Serializable> params = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
    params.put("url", newFile.toURI().toURL());
    params.put("create spatial index", Boolean.TRUE);

    ShapefileDataStore newDataStore = (ShapefileDataStore) dataStoreFactory.createNewDataStore(params);

    /*
     * TYPE is used as a template to describe the file contents
     */
    newDataStore.createSchema(TYPE);
```

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is here - have you tried to just not add the point if the speed is less than 5?

Comment: how can i do that should i place the function before ading the point i really tried a lot of stufss before adding the point but it dosent work ....    any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you want to do something like this:

```
double speed = Double.parseDouble(tokens[5].trim()); // fifth token is speed?

if(speed < 5) {
    /* Longitude (= x coord) first ! */
    Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude));

    /*add features .... */
}
```

Comment: thaank you @kutschkem  for your answer but here i want to delete all rows that the speed are less than 5  but once the speed is more than 5 the function should stop  and we add points event if the speed is  less than 5    i want to use this for truck application cause the gps even if the truck is off he still counting the points but the speed is less than 5 at this moment  so i have to delete them in other way i have to add points ust when the truck is on ....hope you ll help me

Comment: @reda The secret to programming is expressing well what you want - Do you want to delete things out of the csv file, or do you just not want to add points with speed less than 5, or do you want to add all the points after the first one that had speed >= 5?

Answer (score 0):

im sorry if im not expressing well but im trying my best to decribe the situation .... in my case i want to add all points after the first one that had speed >=5  and i found how to do that  but the probleme that i have to do the same thing  from the top ans from the bottom  of the csv file   wish means that the function should start  once again from the bottom to

```
        boolean foundAnyRowHigherThan5 = false;
        for (line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {
            if (line.trim().length() > 0) { // skip blank lines
                String tokens[] = line.split("\\,");
                String name1 = tokens[0].trim();
                String name2 = tokens[1].trim();
                double latitude = Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);
                double longitude = Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]);
                String name = tokens[4].trim();
                String speedString = tokens[5].trim();

                float speedFloat = Float.parseFloat(speedString);

              if(foundAnyRowHigherThan5 || speedFloat > 5.0) {
                // from this point forward, you will not skip lines based on speed.
                if(!foundAnyRowHigherThan5) {
                  foundAnyRowHigherThan5 = true;
                }

                /* Longitude (= x coord) first ! */
                Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude));

                featureBuilder.add(point);
                featureBuilder.add(name1);
                featureBuilder.add(name2);
                featureBuilder.add(name);
                featureBuilder.add(speedString);
                SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);
                features.add(feature);
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
```